# Complex integration: normally on a closed contour?

Tags: soft-question, complex-integration

I have been studying complex integration for a few months now, and it seems my textbook mostly considers integration on closed contours.

Is there no interest in integration on non-closed contours ?

Comment: It depends what you mean: there is interest in contours that go to $\infty$, like the Hankel contour. If you mean curves that really don't divide the plane, the analytic theory does not have particular features beyond those that the real theory has: there's nothing like the residue theorem. On the other hand, if you go non-analytic, you can obtain some results. I think you can formulate something like a Riemann–Hilbert problem on a non-closed contour (this isn't an answer because I don't remember enough details at the moment).

Comment: In practice you can get a lot of mileage from the idea of *closing* a non-closed contour then using the available theory.

Answer (score 0):

To use residue theory, you need a closed contour. If you just have a non-closed contour, it may as well just be a line integral in $\mathbb{R}^2$. The whole point of complex integration theory is to apply the powerful machinery of Cauchy's theorem, and so given a regular integral you look for ways to close it in the complex plane.